# Djangoのdjango-allauthでLINEログインをする認証機能をつくろうとしたが、まったく動かない。

Tags: python, django

参考記事：
https://qiita.com/mutax/items/a7111029a3bd2dfd7772

os:windows 環境は仮想環境でアクティベート済みの状態。
モジュール周りのインストールは済んでおり、プロジェクトの設定をsettings.pyから記事通り設定したが、マイグレーションのところで積んでます。

これが解決すればLINEログインをDjangoの管理サイトに登録する。というステップに移れるのですが…

Comment: 「マイグレーションのところで積んでます」という部分を詳しく説明すると、回答が得られ易いと思います。